# Is this Asbestos?

Tags: asbestos

I found this as insulation layer in an oven (Ariston) while trying to replace a thermocouple and it looks like asbestos to me.

Is it Asbestos? Is it dangerous?

(click to enlarge images)
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Duplicate of [Does this look like asbestos insulation?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/142113/does-this-look-like-asbestos-insulation)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Where have you seen asbestos ? When I dug it out of a 50 lb bag in the back of a store room that everybody forgot;  100 % Asbestos was a fluffy grey powder . I mixed it with sodium silicate to make my own muffler cement before auto exhaust were stainless ( which are great). The material in the photo looks exactly as @ trond said ,fiberglass /mineral wool  as used in appliances, etc  : probably not fiberfrax which is for high temperature and more costly . For home insulation the fiberglas is usually pink.

Comment: `+1` and of course you are strongly advising against others digging asbestos out of old bags and playing with it now, correct?

Comment: I did hold my breath when I stuck my head into the bag.  . And I do not recommend it ,  one should get a car with stainless exhaust. That was 70's , I am certain that long ago the room was cleaned and asbestos properly dispose of .

Comment: Is it safe? Googling it said it can be as hazardous as asbestos but i will trust doubling the coronamask

Comment: Fiberglas can give off irritating short fiber bits. The modern fiberglas ( 30 + years ) are very good at not having the irritating fibers break off  . So it is safe. 25 years ago I put all the pink fibergas batts in my house and garage and was not bothered by any irritation from the fiberglas.

Answer (score 0):

This looks more like fiberglass to me.  That doesn't make it safe to handle- fiberglass can give you truly nasty splinters that are next to impossible to extract.